# How to point a domain to an already existing heroku app, in a way that URL stays unchanged

Tags: web, heroku, dns

I bought a domain name, www.toolshedfingerboards.com , and I already have a functioning heroku site here:
http://toolshedfingerboards.herokuapp.com/
I simply want to connect my domain to he heroku, and so I put the CNAME correclt, but when I go to www.toolshedfingerboards.com the URL automatically gets changed (as if an automatic redirect happens) from that of the domain (http://www.toolshedfingerboards.com) to that of heroku's (http://toolshedfingerboards.herokuapp.com/) . What else do I have to change, so that URL does not get changed? Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: "but the URL gets changed from that of the domain… to that of heroku's"—where and when does this happen? When you first load the page? When you click a navigation link? It's likely that your application simply doesn't know what its base URL should be. What tech did you use to build it?

Comment: I updated my question, so please read again. When I first load the page, yes, it seems as if an automatic redirection happens (redirection from http://www.toolshedfingerboards.com to http://toolshedfingerboards.herokuapp.com)

Comment: It is not getting to the application, the problem is not in the application, the problem is something with config of domain.

Comment: It looks like you're using WordPress, which [will need its domain to be updated](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). I'm pretty sure that's at least part of the issue here. Also, have you added `www.toolshedfingerboards.com` to your [Heroku domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain)? (That can also be done via the web UI.)

Comment: Yesterday something was doing a redirect (I think it was a 301) and that something was running [vegur](https://github.com/heroku/vegur), Heroku's proxy library. Today it seems to be working properly (not redirecting). Did you change something, or did you just need to wait a bit?